# Curve-fitting with uncertainties in fixed parameters of function to fit (Python)

Tags: python, curve-fitting, uncertainty

I have a function that looks like `f(x, m, E, I) = m * (x - x ** 2) / (E * I)`, where I want to get a value for `E`. I have some data, which I call `X` and `Y`, and some uncertainty in the y data which I call `yerr`. Additionally the parameters `m` and `I` are physical quantities, and they have been measured with some uncertainty.

I want to fit the function `f` to my data `X, Y`, having into account the uncertainties of the quantities `m, I`. Right now this is the command I am using to do the fit:

```
m = some value
I = some other value
popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda x, E: f(x, m, E, I), X, Y, p0=[1e9], sigma=yerr)
```

Of course this doesn't take into account the uncertainty in `m` and `I`. Is there any way to fit a curve having into account this uncertainties?

For instance, [here](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/category/uncertainty/) they solve a ODE using the module uncertainties, I tried to copy the procedure but didn't work:

```
import uncertainties as u

def f(x, m, E, I):
    return m * (x - x ** 2) / (E * I)

m = u.ufloat(3e-4, 0.1e-6)
I = u.ufloat(1e-10, 0.2e-12)

@u.wrap
def fit():
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda x, E: f(x, m, E, I), X, Y, p0=[1e9], sigma=yerr)
    return popt, pcov
```

where `X, Y, yerr` are the data and the error in `Y` as mentioned before.

Comment: Do you only have the uncertainties available or all the data sets which the uncertainties are based on? What do you mean by 'didn't work'? What goes wrong?

Comment: @Cleb, I found out that the wrapping does not work because the function that is being wrapped has to return only one float. It looks as though the wrapping just calls the function many times with all the possible combinations of possible variables' values with uncertainties. I will edit the question tomorrow.

Comment: @VladimirVargas I'm facing a similar problem right now. Did you found a way to get your code running or did you try another method? Any kind of hint is appreciated!